# How to access a as3 class from another folder in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Please see the example that i want to ask:

```
1) Main/ProjectFolder/MyProject.fla
2) Main/AS_Classes/CommonClass.as
```

ok, i have a commonClass.as file in different folder. I created a flash file 'MyProject.fla' in ProjectFolder and i want to import CommonClass.as file inside MyProject file.
But i don't know how to access that as3 file. Any Suggestion for this?

Thank You

Comment: which compiler do you use? Flash Builder or Flash Pro, or something else?

Comment: This may help http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/as3_cookbook_excerpts.html

Answer (score 2):

```
include "../../AS_Classes/CommonClass.as";
```

if you import `Class` file, you should add Main/AS_Classes folder to Library path in Publish Setting (ActionScript 3.0 Settings) of MyProject.fla, like this:
[image: as3-libary-path-settings]

then

```
import CommonClass;
```

please make sure your CommonClass using default package.

Comment: Classes should be imported, not included.

Comment: @shanegao ok i understand :), but is there any alternate of path format like "../../" . is that work if i use "~/" like in PHP we use "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]" too access root folder directly. Is AS3 have something like that???